# @Category and MockitoJunitRunner fails to exclude tests

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit, integration-testing, surefire

`@Category` and `MockitoJunitRunner` fails to exclude tests, So I'm categorizing tests using `@Category` (fastTest.class), then I use the  `<group>fastTest.class</group>` to run only the fastTest annotated tests, which works fine and dandy until the test includes the 
`@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)`, any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The problem is that any Tests using @RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class) will run even if it's not included in the category. I only want the @Category(fastTest.class) annotated tests to run.

Comment: Oh, nevermind that wasn't the real problem, the real problem is that I was using surefire version 2.7.2. switching to 2.16 solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

Surefire version out of date, using 2.16 worked.